# How do I open a popup window and display a chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scatter-plot

I have a code, which shows a tooltip and when u click the tootltip a new window will open.
I need to open a popup on onclick function and display my Google scatter chart.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
 $(function() {
   $( '#canvas1' ).tooltip({
      content: "Click Indicator to see Scatter Plot",
      position: { my: "left+140 center", at: "right center" }
   });
 });

 $( '#canvas1' ).click(function() {
    window.open("ANY SITE");
 });
</script>
```

Comment: What does JSP have to do with this?

Comment: The code is a javascript but was written in jsp. So I thought to tag jsp too. @Huangism corrected my mistake.